# Pass a function and all its subfunctions into njit

Tags: python, numba

So I recently discovered Numba and I am thoroughly amazed by it. When trying it out I've used a bubblesort function as the test function, but since my bubblesort function calls another function I get errors when calling njit on it.

I've tackled this by first calling njit on my bubblesort subfunction, and then having my bubblesort call the njit subfunction, and it works, but it forces me to define two bubblesort functions when trying to compare. I'm wondering if there's another way of doing this.

This is what I'm doing:

```
def bytaintill(l):
    changed = False
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        if l[i] > l[i+1]:
            l[i], l[i+1] = l[i+1], l[i]
            changed = True
    return changed


bytaintill_njit = njit()(bytaintill)

def bubblesort(l):
    not_done = True
    while not_done:
        not_done = bytaintill_njit(l)
    return

def bubble(l):
    not_done = True
    while not_done:
        not_done = bytaintill(l)
    return

bubblesort_njit = njit()(bubblesort)
```

Comment: Do you need both the jited and non-jited version defined at the same time? Otherwise you could use an `do_jit` boolean and if the condition evaluates true, simply replace both functions with their jited version.

Comment: @Bob Well, not really, apart from when testing the jited version, So there isn't a way of "jiting" functions with many subfunctions?

Comment: AFAIK no, you'll need to separately define a numba version for all subfunctions. But it's not a big deal, specifically when you do so using the `@njit` decorator.

Comment: @Bob That's when you state @ njit over your function, right? Does that njit the coming function?

Comment: Yes, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you don't need to define new functions but can also map the jit-ed version to the same name. Usually, the most convenient way to do so is to use the `@jit` decorator (or `@njit` which is short for `@jit(nopython=True)`).

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def bytaintill(l):
    changed = False
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        if l[i] > l[i+1]:
            l[i], l[i+1] = l[i+1], l[i]
            changed = True
    return changed

@njit
def bubble(l):
    not_done = True
    while not_done:
        not_done = bytaintill(l)
    return
```

For benchmarking purposes, you can simply comment out the decorators. If you prefer to be able to go forth and back between jit-ed and python versions, you could instead try something like this:

```
from numba import njit

do_jit = True  # set to True or False

def bytaintill(l):
    changed = False
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        if l[i] > l[i+1]:
            l[i], l[i+1] = l[i+1], l[i]
            changed = True
    return changed

def bubble(l):
    not_done = True
    while not_done:
        not_done = bytaintill(l)
    return

if do_jit:
    bytaintill = njit()(bytaintill)
    bubble = njit()(bubble)
```

Comment: Thanks! Are there any downsides to using decorators?

Comment: Nothing I am aware of. Under the hood it does exactly the same as calling `bytaintill = njit()(bytaintill)` and `bubble = njit()(bubble)` yourself. @LegendWK